# Angular Material 2 - Custom mat-option/md-option template in autocomplete

Tags: angular, autocomplete, angular-material

Does Angular Material 2 have a selector to customize autocomplete options like Angular Material `md-item-template` for AngularJS? I couldn't find anything on the [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview) from Material 2

AngularJS example from the [docs](https://material.angularjs.org/1.0.2/demo/autocomplete):

```
<md-autocomplete
    <md-item-template>
      <span class="item-title">
        <md-icon md-svg-icon="img/icons/octicon-repo.svg"></md-icon>
        <span> {{item.name}} </span>
      </span>
      <span class="item-metadata">
        <span class="item-metastat">
          <strong>{{item.watchers}}</strong> watchers
        </span>
        <span class="item-metastat">
          <strong>{{item.forks}}</strong> forks
        </span>
      </span>
    </md-item-template>
</md-autocomplete>
```

[image]

Comment: Just press `<>` at the top right corner (as on your screenshot) and you will see the code for this example. This way you can see HTML, JS and CSS code of the example.

Comment: @CommercialSuicide I know this example from AngularJS, I'm asking if [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/) has this option too. Sorry if you did not understand my question.

Comment: Sorry, my fault

Answer (score 9):

The solution for two line mat-autocomplete with picture

```html
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input matInput placeholder="State" aria-label="State" [matAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="stateCtrl">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let state of filteredStates | async" [value]="state.name">
        <img style="vertical-align:middle;" aria-hidden src="{{state.flag}}" height="20" />
        <span>{{ state.name }}</span> <br>
        <small>Population: {{state.population}}</small>
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

```
// CSS
.mat-option {
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I am also searching for the right way to do it like good 'ol Material 1.
This is ugly hack I could get it to work in Material 5:

Style:

```
.mat-option {
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

Template:

```
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let state of filteredStates | async" [value]="state.name">
    <!-- <img style="vertical-align:middle;" aria-hidden src="{{state.flag}}" height="25" /> -->
        <span>{{ state.name }}</span><br>
        <small>Population: {{state.population}}</small>         
    </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

Try it [here](https://angular-7ahsuk.stackblitz.io)

Comment: Thank you for this solution. It was difficult to find multi-line selection option in angular 2+.

Comment: The problem is that when navigating the list with the arrow keys, the list scrolles up much faster then needed because material thinks every option is 48 px height.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I did to have a multiline option in mat-autocomplete.
For me, the key was to wrap the mat-option content in a div and set display to inline-block.
Maybe someone find it useful.

Template

```
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let item of filteredItems" [value]="item">
    <div class="multiline-option">
      {{ item.lineOne }} <br />
      {{ item.lineTwo }}
    </div>
  </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

Style

```
.multiline-option {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: normal;
}
```